# PHP: stream_copy_to_stream != $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a website written in PHP and on this website, I use [Andrew Valums' "Ajax Upload" JavaScript](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/), which uses XHR for uploading files in browsers that support it and a hidden iframe for the other browsers. When XHR is used, my PHP script makes sure `stream_copy_to_stream($source, $dest)` is equal to `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` (this is how the sample PHP script was). Even though I wasn't sure of the reasoning for this check when I implemented this, I left the code there anyway. It turns out there have been a few times when users have uploaded files and those two values have been different. I'm wondering what causes this. I'm guessing it's a network timeout, but is this the only thing that could cause it? Also, is there ever a time that `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` would not be set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the network connection is interrupted (e.g., user navigates away, clicks 'stop', etc), you won't get all data, and your stream length will be shorter than the `Content-Length` header.
2. `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is unset if no `Content-Length` header is set. This should happen only when `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.